# Can you theoretically form plutonium 238 form plutonium 239? And if so then how and what are its limitations?

Tags: nuclear-engineering, nuclear-isomers

Basically if we could convert plutonium 239 to 238 then we could create space fuel from nuclear waste but if it is possible then what are its limitations due to which this process is not generally in use?

Comment: ENSDF (https://www.nndc.bnl.gov/ensdf/) lists 4 known reactions. The most 'normal' one is 239Pu(D,T)238Pu. Several, including (D,T) are summarized in Nuclear Data Sheets 127, p191 (2015) (https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0090375215000265). Given the (D,T) reaction is at 12MeV D and a FWHM of 15keV, this is not a particularly useful reaction for production of anything.